# The validation error was 'expected RubyGems version 2.4.3, was 2.2.2'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, continuous-integration

I was running my tests in our CI environment and couldn't figure this error out. I realized after a lot of googling that my **local** rubygems was out of date. When it bundled some of our local in-house gems, we got this error:

`The gemspec at
/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/company_name/project/vendor/cache/company-gems-123456789abcdef/task/task.gemspec
is not valid. The validation error was 'expected RubyGems version 2.4.3, was
2.2.2'`

I couldn't figure out if I needed to declare which version of RubyGems to target.

**The fix is to run `gem update --system`, delete your cached gems and `bundle install`**

This sets the version to the version your CI system will use.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to run `gem update --system`, delete your cached gems and `bundle install`.

This sets the version to the version your CI system will use.